# String Reference to an instance of a string

Tags: c#, mysql

So; after changing hosting companies; i'm now receiving this error in my mysql code; even after updating the ip, database name, uid, and it's password. The error i'm receiving is:

> Error is: `System.ArgumentNullException`: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
>
> Parameter name: s
>
> ```
>    at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
>    at BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(String text, String hash, Boolean enhancedEntropy, HashType hashType)
>    at NGH.MainScreen.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in > C:\Users\SHADOWGHOSTS\Desktop\NGH\NGH\MainScreen.cs:line 246
> ```

and as such, this is my code below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string server = "72.167.59.139";
    string database = "DATABASENAMEHERE";
    string uid = "USERIDHERE";
    string password = "PASSWORDHERE";
    string ssl = "None";
    string connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};SSL Mode={ssl};";  
    using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT members_pass_hash FROM core_members WHERE name = @name AND mgroup_others = 7 AND member_hwid = @hwid;", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hwid", HWIDNumber);

    var hashedPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    try
    {
        if (!(hashedPassword is null && !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(maskedTextBox2.Text, hashedPassword)))
        {

            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.username = maskedTextBox1.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.password = maskedTextBox2.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            var vip = new vipmember();
            //CHECKHWID();
            vip.Show();
            HM();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error is: " + ex);
        //MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex);
        //MessageBox.Show("Either you have entered the wrong login information, you are not VIP, or your HWID does not match.");
        //MessageBox.Show("Please Copy and Paste this message and give it to the owner: " + HWIDNumber + " Select this MessageBox and press Ctrl + c to Copy it's content!");
        //MessageBox.Show("Either Login information is Incorrect or You are not VIP.");               
    }

    //CHECKHWID();
}
```

I have tried making another database user, changing it's password, and yet it doesn't work. I don't know what to do.

Comment: It looks like you are passing a null string into Verify.  `hashedPassword is null && ..Verify`.  So Verify only runs when the hashedPassword is null, that doesnt look right..

Comment: @hijinxbassist that can not be right, as it was working prior to moving to different hosting companies.

Comment: Which line is line 246?

Comment: Maybe a paren got moved and it was suppose to be `!(hashedPassword is null) && ..`  It seems very suspect that the condition would explicitly want a null string and then proceed to use it.  Check the value of `maskedTextBox2.Text`, maybe im just misinterpreting the `hashPassword` portion.

Comment: @hijinxbassist Even if I made the `if (!(hashedPassword is null && BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(maskedTextBox2.Text, hashedPassword)))` it still shows the same error. `maskedTestBox2.Text` is the password field, which is filled out before the attempted login.

Comment: I don't see the change reflected in your comment.  `if (!(hashedPassword is null) && BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(maskedTextBox2.Text, hashedPassword))` is what i meant.  Have you been able to confirm that you are connected to the correct database and can query it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are passing null to the `BCrypt` function.
The database is returning null, and your condition does not prevent passing a null value to the `BCrypt` function - notice that the condition says: `if hashedPassword IS null` [...]

Modify the code to:

```
if (!(hashedPassword is null) && BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(maskedTextBox2.Text, hashedPassword))
```

Now, if `hashedPassword` is null, the entire condition will return false, and it will no longer execute the `BCrypt` function with a null `hashedPassword` value (which causes an error).